# I am trying to display data from rows by date column in android app

Tags: android, database, sqlite, rows

I am writing editText and textView to a database in my app. I want to display what they added by a specific column; which I have as DATE_SELECTED. I am having a major block and any help would be appreciated. Below is my code for this section:

```
public class CalendarDBAdapter 
{
    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String DATE_SELECTED = "date";
    public static final String WEIGHT_INPUT = "weight";
    public static final String REPS_INPUT = "reps";
    public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "id";

    private static final String TAG = "CalendarDBAdapter";
    private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "exerciselog";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "exercises";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //Database creation sql statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                                                  + KEY_TITLE + DATE_SELECTED + WEIGHT_INPUT + REPS_INPUT + " text not null);";
    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            try  
            {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } 
            catch (SQLException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TSBLE IF EXISTS exercises");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    //constructor
    public CalendarDBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    /*
     * Open exercises database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new instance of the database
     * If it cannot be created, trow and exception to signal failure
     * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
     *         initialization call)
     * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
     */
    public CalendarDBAdapter open()throws SQLException
    {
        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        myDatabase = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        myDBHelper.close();
    }

    /*
     * Create a new exercise using the title provided. If the note is
     * successfully created return the new rowId for that exercise, otherwise return
     * a -1 to indicate failure.
     * 
     * @param title the title of the exercise
     * @return rowId or -1 if failed
     */
    public long createExercise(String title, String date, String weight, String reps, String body)
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        initialValues.put(DATE_SELECTED, date);
        initialValues.put(WEIGHT_INPUT, weight);
        initialValues.put(REPS_INPUT, reps);
        initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);
        return myDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    /*
     * Delete exercise with given rowId
     * @param rowId id of exercise to delete
     * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean deleteExercise(long rowID)
    {
        return myDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowID, null) > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor over the list of all exercise inputs in the database
     * 
     * @return Cursor over all exercise inputs
     */
    public Cursor fetchAllExercises()
    {
        return myDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, DATE_SELECTED, WEIGHT_INPUT, REPS_INPUT, KEY_BODY}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Return a Cursor positioned at the exercise that matches the given rowId
     * 
     * @param rowId id of exercise to retrieve
     * @return Cursor positioned to matching note, if found
     * @throws SQLException if note could not be found/retrieved
     */
    public Cursor fetchExerciss(long rowId)throws SQLException
    {
        Cursor myCursor = 
                myDatabase.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, DATE_SELECTED, WEIGHT_INPUT, REPS_INPUT, KEY_BODY}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId,
                        null, null, null, null, null);
        if(myCursor != null)
        {
            myCursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        return myCursor;
    }

    /**
     * Update the exercises using the details provided. The note to be updated is
     * specified using the rowId, and it is altered to use the title values passed in
     * 
     * @param rowId id of exercise to update
     * @param title value to set exercise title to
     * @param body value to set exercise body to
     * @return true if the exercise was successfully updated, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean updateExercise(long rowID, String title, String date, String weight, String reps, String body)
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
        args.put(DATE_SELECTED, date);
        args.put(WEIGHT_INPUT, weight);
        args.put(REPS_INPUT, reps);
        args.put(KEY_BODY, body);
        return myDatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowID, null) > 0;
    }

    public Cursor sortAllRows()
    {
        return myDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE, DATE_SELECTED, WEIGHT_INPUT, REPS_INPUT, KEY_BODY}, 
                                    null, null, null, null, DATE_SELECTED + " ASC");
    }



}
```

Activity:

```
package com.mobifit;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

import com.mobifit.R.string;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AddToCalendar extends Activity 
{
    private Button favBtn;
    private Button timerBtn;
    private Button editBtn;
    private Button selectedDMY;
    private Button addCalBtn;
    private TextView exercise, exerciseDB, weightText, repsText, notesText;
    private String textPassed, datePassed;
    private EditText weightInput, repsInput, notesInput;
    private Long myRowID;
    private CalendarDBAdapter myDBHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        myDBHelper = new CalendarDBAdapter(this);
        myDBHelper.open();
        setContentView(R.layout.add_to_calendar);

        //set view from xml
        favBtn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.favoriteBtn);
        timerBtn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.timerBtn);
        editBtn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.editBtn);
        addCalBtn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.addToCalBtn);
        weightInput = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.weightInput);
        repsInput = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.repsInput);
        notesInput = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.notesInput);
        exerciseDB = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.exerciseDB);
        weightText = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.weight);
        repsText = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.repsText);
        notesText = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.notesText);

        //set date 
        selectedDMY = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.selectedDayMonthYear);
        datePassed = GlobalVars.getDate();
        if(datePassed == null)
        {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            Integer.toString(day);
            Integer.toString(month);
            Integer.toString(year);

            selectedDMY.setText("Today" + month + "-" + day + "-" + year + "\n(click to change)");
        }
        else
        {
            selectedDMY.setText(datePassed + "\n(click to change)");
        }

        exercise = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.exercise);

        //enable button
        favBtn.setEnabled(true);
        timerBtn.setEnabled(true);
        editBtn.setEnabled(true);
        selectedDMY.setEnabled(true);

        //set text for exercise passed
        textPassed = GlobalVars.getVar();
        exercise.setText(textPassed);

        //rowID for database
        myRowID = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null: (Long)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(CalendarDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
        if(myRowID == null)
        {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            myRowID = extras != null ? extras.getLong(CalendarDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID): null;
        }
        //populateFields();

        addCalBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {

            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                //previous code
                /*setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();*/ 

            }
        });
    }

    public void dateClick(View v)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MobiFitCalendar.class));
    }

    //add the data to the calendar for display
    public void addToCalBtnClick()
    {

    }

    private void populateFields()
    {
        if(myRowID != null)
        {
            Cursor exerciseInput = myDBHelper.fetchExerciss(myRowID);
            startManagingCursor(exerciseInput);         
            weightInput.setText(exerciseInput.getString(exerciseInput.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CalendarDBAdapter.WEIGHT_INPUT)));
            repsInput.setText(exerciseInput.getString(exerciseInput.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CalendarDBAdapter.REPS_INPUT)));
            notesInput.setText(exerciseInput.getString(exerciseInput.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CalendarDBAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        saveState();
        outState.putSerializable(CalendarDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID, myRowID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        saveState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        populateFields();
    }

    private void saveState()
    {
        String title = exercise.toString();
        String weight = weightInput.getText().toString();
        String reps = weightInput.getText().toString();
        String notes = notesInput.getText().toString();
        String dateSelected = selectedDMY.toString();

        if(myRowID == null)
        {
            long id = myDBHelper.createExercise(title, dateSelected, weight, reps, notes);
            if(id > 0)
            {
                myRowID = id;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            myDBHelper.updateExercise(myRowID, title, dateSelected, weight, reps, notes);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_to_calendar, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: the ratio between the code and your explanation is very large, maybe give a better explanation of the `problem`.

Comment: The user input is set to the database, but I can't figure out how to query and print for the android OS. I want to be able to query the database based on the the date string that is passed and only display all that data for that day. Basically I think its a question of how to query correctly for this OS based on that criteria.

Comment: JDBC is your friend, since for programming Android we use Java, then is logical that JDBC is the way to treat the embedded SQLite database of Android